# My transistor level half-adder works in spice but not in real life

Tags: resistor-transistor-logic

I'm trying to build a transistor level half-adder. I am using each transistor as a NOR gate (see below).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRUbxr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The half-adder logic circuit I am using is this one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNJnlD.png)</sup>
This is the full circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWMS2B.png)</sup>

I have built this circuit in my spice program and it works, but it didn't work when I built it on a breadboard.[image: Breadboard circuit]

I'm pretty sure I wired it correctly, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Show your full schematic please.

Comment: Have you noticed how a switch as an input to your transistor circuit does not match the case where a transistor circuit drives another transistor circuit?

Comment: @Justme I'm sorry I didn't understand could you clarify

Comment: Isn't the output also just connected to ground. Also, since you say the spice simulation works, show it, and aince you say breadboard doesn not work, in what way it works then? What does as expected, what doesn't?

Comment: @Justme The output would be connected to ground through an LED. On the breadboard it was connected to a multimeter. And on the breadboard the output would be high whenever I pressed any switch.

Comment: "but it didn't work" - In what way did it not work? What inputs did you give it and what outputs did it give back? What measurements have you made to debug the issues?

Answer (score 3):

On the breadboard, rotate all 3 transistors by 180 degrees.

Comment: Yup. In the photo you supplied, your current orientation has the collectors at the top and these are all grounded (through A-E13), so clearly should have been the emitters.

Comment: @joupy Are those transistors on the breadboard 2N3904s as you have shown in the circuit diagram?